# How to delete the last character of prior line with sed

Tags: json, bash, sed

I'm trying to delete a line with a the last character of the prior line with sed:

I have a json file :

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":"16",
"country":"Spain"
}
```

I would like to delete country of all entries, to do that I have to delete the comma for the json syntax of the prior line.

I'm using this pattern :

```
sed '/country/d' test.json
sed -n '/resolved//.$//{x;d;};1h;1!{x;p;};${x;p;}' test.json
```

---

<sup>**Editor's note**:

The OP later clarified the following additional requirements, which invalidated some of the existing answers:

- *multiple* occurrences of `country` properties should be removed

- *across all levels* of the object hierarchy

- whitespace variations should be tolerated</sup>

Comment: I wonder why `sed`?
 There are plenty of tools capable of parsing JSON. Consider using `jq`, `perl`, `php`, or something with a built-in JSON parser.

Comment: I would prefer SHELL, cause i'm will be using the command in a jenkins job

Comment: "I would prefer SHELL": there are tools you can use to manipulate json from a shell script. e.g., jq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using a proper JSON parser such as `jq` is generally the best choic**e (see below), but if installing a utility is not an option, try this ***GNU* `sed` command**:

```
$ sed -zr 's/,\s*"country":[^\n]+//g' test.json
{
"name":"John",
"age":"16"
}
```

- `-z` splits the input into records by `NUL`s, which, in this case means that the *whole file* is read at once, which enables cross-line substitutions.
- `-r` enables *extended* regular expressions for a more modern syntax with more features.
- `s/,\n"country":\s*//g` replaces all occurrences of a comma followed by a (possibly empty) run of whitespace (including possibly a newline) and then `"country"` through the end of that line with the empty string, i.e., effectively *removes* the matched strings.

  - Note that this assumes that no other property or closing `}` *follows* such a `country` property on the same line.

---

To demonstrate **a more robust solution based on [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)**.

<sup>[Bertrand Martel's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40360477/45375) contains a `jq` solution, which, however, does not address the requirement (added *later*) of replacing `country` attributes anywhere in the input object hierarchy.</sup>

In a not-yet-released version of `jq` higher than `v1.5.2`, a builtin `walk/1` function will be available, which enables the following simple solution:

```
# Walk all nodes and remove a "country" property from any object.
jq 'walk(if type == "object" then del (.country) else . end)' test.json
```

In `v1.5.2` and below, you can define a simplified variant of `walk` yourself:

```
jq '
  # Define recursive function walk_objects/1 that walks all objects in the
  # hierarchy.
  def walk_objects(f): . as $in | 
    if type == "object" then
      reduce keys[] as $key
        ( {}; . + { ($key):  ($in[$key] | walk_objects(f)) } ) | f
    elif type == "array" then map( walk_objects(f) )
    else . end;
  # Walk all objects and remove a "country" property, if present.
  walk_objects(del(.country))
' test.json
```

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out before you should really consider using a JSON parser to parse JSON.

When that is said you can slurp the whole file, remove newlines and then replace
accordantly:

```
$ sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n//g;s/,"country"[^}]*//' test.json
{"name":"John","age":"16"}
```

Breakdown:

```
:a;                 # Define label 'a'
   N;               # Append next line to pattern space
     $!ba;          # Goto 'a' unless it's the last line
s/\n//g;            # Replace all newlines with nothing
s/,"country"[^}]*// # Replace ',"country...' with nothing
```

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 'N;s/,\s*\n\s*"country".*//;P;D' file
```

Read two lines into the pattern space and remove substitution string.

N.B. Allows for spaces either side of the line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON parser like [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) to parse json file. The following will return the document without the `country` field and write the new document in `result.json` :

```
jq 'del(.country)' file.json > result.json
```

Comment: @YasserB. your json file does not have multiple or nested keys.

Comment: Check this gist : https://gist.github.com/akinaru/120cb4583b60b0dc77f1012bc5f4a9f8 for a complete example

Comment: Thanks for your answer